# What may be the possible causes that my cast is failing

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am trying to make a vehicle selection system in ue4 with blueprints.
I have followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLVS-tzDUBU).

Below are the screenshots of my code.
[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXJ2d.png) and
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaeYC.png)

firstly I tried to figure out what is happening to my code then I came to know that the cast was not succedding and hence the car is being spawned but not posessed.

please help me by listing some reasons that may be responsible for this.
if you want any info so I have given the link of the video which I have used to make the system.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I found the answer

I just searched it on Google and found it here:
https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/98622/view.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).